# Show that $\pi$ is isomorphic to a subrepresentation of the representation of $G$ on $C_2(X)$

Tags: representation-theory

I am looking at the following problem in relation to representation theory

> Suppose $G$ is a compact group that acts transitively on a topological space $X$. Let $x_0 \in X$ and let $H \leq G$ be the isotropy group of $x_0$. Suppose $\pi : G \to GL(V)$ is a finite-dimensional complex representation such that there exist $v \in V \setminus \lbrace 0 \rbrace$ with $\pi (h) v = v$ for all $h \in H$. Show that $\pi$ is isomorphic to a subrepresentation of the representation of $G$ on $C_2(X)$ (HINT: First prove that there exists an H-invariant $f \in V' \setminus \lbrace 0 \rbrace$, then use this to construct an appropriate subrepresentation)

Firstly, I noted that the isotropy group of $x_0$ is $H:= \lbrace g \in G : g \cdot x_0 = x_0 \rbrace$ and then tried to follow the hint provided. I know that given a representation $\pi: G \to GL(V)$ there exist a representation $\text{Res}^G_H: H \to GL(V)$ by restricting $\pi$ to $H$.

By definition, Res$^G_H \pi$ is H-invariant if and only if Res$^G_H\pi (h) v \in V \setminus \lbrace 0 \rbrace$ for all $h \in H$ and $v \in V \setminus \lbrace 0 \rbrace$. By assumption we have that there exist a $v \in V \setminus \lbrace 0 \rbrace$ with $\pi (h) v = v$ for all $h \in H$, thus we obtain in particular that Res$^G_H\pi (h) v \in V \setminus \lbrace 0 \rbrace$ so $\pi_H$ is H-invariant. So I believe that this could be the $f$ the hint wanted me to be looking for.

Now I have two questions:

1. Is the first part correct? I am not sure if the definition of "invariant" is to be read as "for all $g \in G$ and for all $v \in V \setminus \lbrace 0 \rbrace$" or if it is read as "for all $g \in G$ and some $v \in V \setminus \lbrace 0 \rbrace$"
2. How does this help me proving that $\pi$ is isomorphic to a subrepresentation of the representation of $G$ on $C_2(X)$?

Comment: It does not make sense to say that $\mathrm{Res}^G_H\pi$ is $H$-invariant, or in general to say that any representation of $H$ is $H$-invariant. Invariance under a group (ie being fixed by its action) is a property of vectors in the representation. Also, what is $C_2(X)$?